# How to store a value from a textbox android?

Tags: android, gps, location

i am developing an gps program in that i am getting gps values for every 5 minutes,
and it is working great, but i have to store the values which i get. it has been refreshed for every 5 minutes and i have only one text view so that it deletes the old values when the new one is refreshed.

this is my code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
         intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
         this.sendBroadcast(intent);

        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
            this.sendBroadcast(poke);


        }
    {
        //initialize location manager
        manager =  (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //check if GPS is enabled
        //if not, notify user with a toast
        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)); else {
            //get a location provider from location manager
            //empty criteria searches through all providers and returns the best one
            String providerName = manager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
            Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(providerName);

            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationResults);
            if (location != null) {
                tv.setText(location.getLatitude() + " latitude, " + location.getLongitude() + " longitude");
            } else {
                tv.setText("Last known location not found. Waiting for updated location...");
            }
            //sign up to be notified of location updates every 15 seconds - for production code this should be at least a minute
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(providerName, 60000, 1, this);
        }
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationResults);
        if (location != null) {
            tv.setText(location.getLatitude() + " latitude, " + location.getLongitude() + " longitude");
        } else {
            tv.setText("Problem getting location");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {}

    // Find the closest Bart Station
    public String findClosestBart(Location loc) {
        double lat = loc.getLatitude();
        double lon = loc.getLongitude();

        double curStatLat = 0;
        double curStatLon = 0;
        double shortestDistSoFar = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        double curDist;
        String curStat = null;
        String closestStat = null;

        //sort through all the stations
        // write some sort of for loop using the API.

        curDist = Math.sqrt( ((lat - curStatLat) * (lat - curStatLat)) +
                        ((lon - curStatLon) * (lon - curStatLon)) );
        if (curDist < shortestDistSoFar) {
            closestStat = curStat;
        }

        return closestStat;

        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: store it in a arraylist

Comment: Append new values in that textview.

Comment: can you show me how to display the locations in list which i get.

Comment: Store the TextView's value in file each time you get a new co-ordinate.

Comment: @Lucifer can you tell me difference between service and intent service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your Textview's value into a file for persistance storage. Study my answer properly, I am adding a file store method in your existing code,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
         intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
         this.sendBroadcast(intent);

        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
            this.sendBroadcast(poke);


        }
    {
        //initialize location manager
        manager =  (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //check if GPS is enabled
        //if not, notify user with a toast
        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)); else {
            //get a location provider from location manager
            //empty criteria searches through all providers and returns the best one
            String providerName = manager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
            Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(providerName);

            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationResults);
            if (location != null) {
                tv.setText(location.getLatitude() + " latitude, " + location.getLongitude() + " longitude");
            } else {
                tv.setText("Last known location not found. Waiting for updated location...");
            }
            //sign up to be notified of location updates every 15 seconds - for production code this should be at least a minute
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(providerName, 60000, 1, this);
        }
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationResults);
        if (location != null) {
            tv.setText(location.getLatitude() + " latitude, " + location.getLongitude() + " longitude");
          // I have added this line
          appendData ( location.getLatitude() + " latitude, " + location.getLongitude() + " longitude" );
        } else {
            tv.setText("Problem getting location");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {}

    // Find the closest Bart Station
    public String findClosestBart(Location loc) {
        double lat = loc.getLatitude();
        double lon = loc.getLongitude();

        double curStatLat = 0;
        double curStatLon = 0;
        double shortestDistSoFar = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        double curDist;
        String curStat = null;
        String closestStat = null;

        //sort through all the stations
        // write some sort of for loop using the API.

        curDist = Math.sqrt( ((lat - curStatLat) * (lat - curStatLat)) +
                        ((lon - curStatLon) * (lon - curStatLon)) );
        if (curDist < shortestDistSoFar) {
            closestStat = curStat;
        }

        return closestStat;

        }   
     // method to write in file 
public void appendData(String text)
{       
   File dataFile = new File("sdcard/gpsData.txt");
   if (!dataFile.exists())
   {
      try
      {
         dataFile.createNewFile();
      } 
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   try
   {
      //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
      BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dataFile, true)); 
      buf.append(text);
      buf.newLine();
      buf.close();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

You need to write following permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: @Lucifer i am new to android and i have got many samples and its running in service but i dont know to edit that can you show me how pls

Answer (score 0):

Well you have plenty of persistence options, but in this case the best is using [SharedPreferences](https://www.google.com.cu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDwQFjAB&url=http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html&ei=syFyUcC9FojBPPSlgfgL&usg=AFQjCNGp43XUcnNOhRE7DytXA07IG44RHw&bvm=bv.45512109,d.ZWU)

Comment: Just a little doubt, How you are going to store multiple lat-lon values in SharedPreference with same Key Value ?

Answer (score 0):

No one can say for sure without knowing exactly what you need to do with the saved data. [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) is a good option if you need to store it temporarily. You can create a new ArrayList then put the value in there at the same time that you use it in `setText()`. If you want something permanent then you will probably want to store it in a DB or a file. Check out [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Also, in this case, a good idea may be to store it in an `ArrayList` temporarily then use that list to transfer them to a file or DB for permanent storage if that's what you want

Another way to store it temporarily, and possibly save somewhere later would be a [HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html). Maybe something in the form of `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>`. Since we don't know your exact intentions with the data, examples could be endless but maybe this will give you a good starting point so you can decide what will work best for you then you can find many examples all over SO and the Google for your choice